# Subset Data Frame which has data frame as variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has multiple variables some that are character vectors and some that are data frames. I'm having trouble subsetting my data frame df1 by a character vector and a set of columns from one of the data frame variables df2.  An example of what I'm trying to do is below, this example does not work.

```
df1[,"vector","df2$field"]
```

Comment: The way you are trying to subset implies a 3D data.frame, which is not possible.

Comment: is this the result of parsing json?  you should post an example of what you have, since this is an unusual data structure in R.

Comment: Use dput to post this malformed object.